# How to create a text shape with python pptx?

Tags: python, tkinter, powerpoint, python-pptx

I want to add a text box to a presentation with `python pptx`. I would like to add a text box with several paragraphs in the specific place and then format it (fonts, color, etc.). But since text shape object always comes with the one paragraph in the beginning, I cannot edit first of my paragraphs. The code sample looks like this:

```
txBox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(left, top, width, height)
tf = txBox.text_frame

p = tf.add_paragraph()
p.text = "This is a first paragraph"
p.font.size = Pt(11)

p = tf.add_paragraph()
p.text = "This is a second paragraph"
p.font.size = Pt(11)
```

Which creates output like this:
[image]

I can add text to this first line with `tf.text = "This is text inside a textbox"`, but it won't be editable in terms of fonts or colors. So is there any way how I can omit or edit that line, so all paragraphs in the box would be the same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Access the first paragraph differently, using:

```
p = tf.paragraphs[0]
```

Then you can add runs, set fonts and all the rest of it just like with a paragraph you get back from `tf.add_paragraph()`.

Comment: Damn, so smooth and easy... Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @scanny. Saved me a lot of time. Surprisingly this is not in the official documentation.